# Cannot vs May not be cured?

Tags: modal-verbs, word-difference

I've been reading about how doctors avoid using the word 'cure' and instead use the word 'remission' for chronic diseases and cancer. So when they avoid using it, does this mean:
a) the treatments CANNOT cure chronic diseases/cancer. 
or 
b) the treatments MAY NOT cure chronic diseases/cancer.(implying there is a possibility that it can be cured)

Which statement is correct?

Answer (score 3):

- "cannot" expresses impossibility.
- "may not" expresses negative probability.

"remission" suggests a temporary improvement. If the disease is chronic or incurable, a definitive cure is unfortunately not possible, so I'd go for:

a) Medical treatments **cannot** cure chronic diseases and some kinds of cancer.

Answer (score 2):

I think both *cannot* and *may not* express judgments beyond the scope of medical evidence.

Here's a quote from a reasonably authoritative source:

> If you remain in complete remission for 5 years or more, some doctors may say that you are cured. Still, some cancer cells can remain in your body for many years after treatment. These cells may cause the cancer to come back one day. For cancers that return, most do so within the first 5 years after treatment. But, there is a chance that cancer will come back later. For this reason, doctors cannot say for sure that you are cured. The most they can say is that there are no signs of cancer at this time.
>   —[(US) National Cancer Institute](https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/diagnosis-staging/prognosis#survival-statistics)

It appears that medical science can say with certainty only that treatments in many cases **do not** cure cancer. In other cases, where patients whose cancers do not recur, science cannot say with any confidence that they are 'cured'; there is consequently no ground for saying whether cure is possible or impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that simple. The word cure is way too general. If you have e.g. an infection then curing it for the layman means getting rid of whatever caused the infection, treating the symptoms and reversing the damage.

Now, in case of chronic diseases, especially with many types of cancer often you can't get rid of the cause or reverse the damage. It's not that treatments won't work and save lives, it's that damage may be permanent and there's always a possibility of recurrence. In many cases you'd need to rewrite the DNA to eliminate that possibility. Many can recover from e.g. osteosarcoma but damage to the bones are sometimes too severe and even amputation may be required, and the possibility of recurrence is never zero. It's hard to say that you're cured if you lost your leg and even if there's no evidence of cancer, the possibility of recurrence remains.

Avoiding the usage of the word cure doesn't imply anything about a treatment's effectiveness, it's just a safer way to phrase things. Nobody wants to raise false hopes, especially when the media often blows things out of proportion. If one claim that *"We're working on a cure for acute lymphoblastic leukemia and it seems promising"* can result in headlines saying *"New Cure for Cancer Found"* in papers all around the globe, then staying cautious about how they phrase things is very important.